# Как найти все элементы до определенного места

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Как при помощи библиотеки `BeautifulSoup` мне найти все элементы до определенного места.
Допустим, у меня идет 3 дива потом идет один заголовок и потом опять 3 дива. Если использовать `.find_all`, то понятное дело находит все дивы, а мне надо получить только те 3, которые стоят до заголовка. Как такое реализовать?

**Наглядный пример:**

```
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<h4>PRIVET</h4>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Через `nextSibling`.